# How to create an AngularJs directive in one node package, and then include it in another node package for the app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, module, bower

If I have a directive, and I wish to package it in its own node package; and then include it from another another node package containing the main angularjs app, how would I do this?

My rough idea about how to go about this is:

- put the html, javascript, and css for the directive in the package folder
- enable compilation of these assets - preprocessing, minification (how?)
- configure as bower package
- in the app folder install the bower package

  - how to do this locally, without publishing?
- in the `angular.module()` statement that creates the main app, add the name of the module containing the directive

Is this correct?
Have I missed out on anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of how to go about this looks good to me. To answer your questions in the list:

Look at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for your preprocessing / minification needs.  These are both excellent build tools.  Grunt is more widely used, but Gulp is newer and gaining a lot of ground.  I'd look at both and use the one that suits you.

How to use a local bower dependency w/o publishing:
In your main app's bower.json file, instead of putting a version number for your module, put the folder where it can be found on your local system, like so:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "my-module": "/home/me/modules/my-module"
  }
}
```

To clarify, you refer to it as a "node package" in your question, but in reality, you are creating a [Bower](http://bower.io) package.  Node packages (published to [npmjs.org](http://npmjs.org)) are for node, and unless processed with something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), won't run in the browser (and even then, the node package can't do anything the browser doesn't support, like file access.)  Bower packages (published on [bower.io](http://bower.io)) are specifically for the browser.  You will however find packages that publish to both NPM & Bower, such as jQuery or underscore, but you can't use the npm jquery package in the browser, it's built to run in node, and vice-a-versa.